# Avoid getting values from drop down lists in hidden div's

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, ddl

I have 5 drop-down lists in 5 divs. those divs visibility becomes true or false based on another drop-down list. when I make a selection on the main DDL some div's visibility becomes false. I want to remove the selectedvalues from hidden divs. (i.e- all the divs don't bind data at page load)

Answer (score 0):

Use Session variables by setting them to null values.